# C++ sqlite3 bind parameters

Tags: c++, sqlite

I've only been playing with the sqlite3 library for C++ for a few days, but it's causing me a great deal of frustration.

I want to define a parameterized CREATE TABLE, and later bind the parameters to it.  It looks something like this:

```
const char[] CREATE_SQL = 
  "CRAETE TABLE t1 ("
  "  name VARCHAR(:NAME_LEN)"
  "  other VARCHAR(:OTHER_LEN)"
  ");";
```

The idea is that in a different file (the .cpp to this header file), I would be able to bind these parameters with:

```
int index = sqlite3_bind_parameter_index(stmt, ":NAME_LEN");
sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, index, _DB_FIELD_SIZE_NAME);
```

where _DB_FIELD_SIZE_NAME is also defined elsewhere.

I don't want to use `sprintf()` with `CREATE_SQL` containing `%d` instead of `:NAME_LEN` and `:OTHER_LEN`, because I might change the order of parameters or add new ones and I'd like to keep the binding explicit.

Now, for the problem: my prepare does not return `SQLITE_OK`, but results in a null pointer for the `sqlite3_stmt`.  Here's what I have:

```
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
const char *pStmt = 0;
if( SQLITE_OK != sqlite3_prepare_v2(*db, CREATE_SQL, -1, &stmt, &pStmt) )
    // throws exception with the sqlite3_errmsg(*db) text
```

So, the error I'm getting is this:

```
near ":NAME_LEN": syntax error
```

What am I doing wrong?  I'm sure that the database connection opens OK.

Comment: You have a typo: "CRAETE" -> "CREATE".  This *could* be what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To not answer your question, sqlite doesn't have strict text column sizing.  It accepts VARCHAR types for compatibility's sake, but has no variance in its behavior.

You'll always end up with something equivalent to this:

```
const char *sql = 
  "CREATE TABLE t1 ("
  "  name TEXT"
  "  ,other TEXT"
  ");";
```

To answer your question, I don't believe you are allowed to do this.  Sqlite's substitution mechanisms only work on what would typically be considered value parameters.

What you'd typically see in `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statements, for instance.

```
const char *sql = "INSERT INTO foo (a,b) VALUES (?1,?);";
```

I don't remember if you can do them in a `CREATE` statement at all, perhaps for a default parameter? It has been a long time.

I've found `boost::format` to be a lot less likely to break and create clearer code than any other solution that I've tried when you have to change non-value parameters.

```
#include <boost/format.hpp>

// ... 

int instance_id = 42;
const char *sql = "CREATE TABLE type_%1% (a,b);";
boost::str( boost::format(sql) % instance_id );
```

I would definitely encourage you to avoid doing non-value parameter replacement unless you **absolutely** have to.  It's a maintenance hassle and error prone.

Comment: Ah, I see.  You're right, I just didn't realize that `TEXT` fields are all the same.
Thank you!